# Quiero hacer un buscador de paises consumiendo una API, pero no renderiza nada

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Estoy tratando de construir un buscador de Paises, consuemiendo una API. El programa no presenta ningun error; sin embargo, al hacer la busqueda no renderiza el pais encontrado o buscado. Hago un console.log con todos los atributos del pais que busco y si los manda. ¿Algo que me recomienden o crean que le falta a mi código? Psdt: Soy principiante en el mundo de React y APIs.
Este es el codigo principal:

```
import { useState , useEffect } from "react"
import { getAllCountries } from "./services/getAllCountries"

const Countrie = ({name , flags}) => {
  return (
      <div>
          <li>
              <p>{name.common}</p>
              <img src= {flags.png}></img>
          </li>
      </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Cargó")
    setTimeout(() => {
      getAllCountries().then((countries) => {
        setCountries(countries)
      })
    }, 2000)
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearched(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    countries.map((countrie) => {
      if(searched === countrie.name.common){
        console.log(countrie)
        return <Countrie name={countrie.name} flags={countrie.flags}/>
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Paises
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={searched}></input>
          <button>Buscar</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Y este es el archivo para traer los datos de la API:

```
import axios from "axios";
export const getAllCountries = () => {
    return axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
    .then(response => {
        const {data} = response
        return data
    })
}
```

Intente trabajar con condicionales para dar con el pais buscado. Esperaba que mostrara el resultado de la busqueda.
Busque en paginas, pero pese a que el fin era el mismo, los codigos que mostraban eran completamente diferentes. Quise hacerlo a mi manera

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lo que estas intentando en `handleSubmit` es un patron inválido en react, usualmente lo que se renderiza en un componente react debe ir dentro del `return del componente`, y no dentro de un método del componente; se podría resolver usando condicionales y estado pero si lo que necesitas es mostrar diferentes componentes en diferentes paginas te sugiero usar vite con react router o algún framework como astro o nextjs.